# NSString eating up memory

Tags: memory, for-loop, nsstring

I have a series of 11 for loops embedded within each other, all of them 0-5:

```
NSPredicate *p
NSString *stringEquation;    

for (i=0; i<6; i++) {

      for (j=0; j<6; j++) {

        etc. . . . .

      }

    }
```

within the last loop, I have evaluate a number of expressions based on these loop iterations:

```
stringEquation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.0%@%d.0%@%d.0%@%d.0==24.0",[[theNumbers objectAtIndex:a] intValue],[someOperators objectAtIndex:v],[[theNumbers objectAtIndex:b] intValue],[someOperators objectAtIndex:w],[[theNumbers objectAtIndex:c] intValue],[someOperators objectAtIndex:x],[[theNumbers objectAtIndex:d] intValue]];

p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:stringEquation];

if ([p evaluateWithObject:nil]) {

  [theMatches addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld,%ld,%ld,%ld,%ld,%ld,%ld",(long)a,(long)b,(long)c,(long)d,(long)v,(long)w,(long)x]];

  fourMatches = fourMatches + 1;

}
```

Both the NSPredicate and the NSString are setup just before the first For loop.  Everything works fine and it's all evaluated correctly; however, the memory use goes up with every iteration through.  Am I doing something wrong here?  I though by reusing the same NSPredicate and NSString variable, I would be saving memory, not increasing its use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've got many nested loops, the reason could be because your code could indeed uses a lot of memory: eleven loops, each completing six times, gives you six to the power of eleven, or 362797056 potential matches, so you could store as many string objects in your `theMatches` collection.

However, a more likely reason is that you've got lots of pending autorelease objects. They are not used, but they keep occupying memory until your method exits, letting the run loop deal with freeing your autoreleased objects. That is, even if not all of these would end up in the collection, there will be a lot of autoreleased objects that need to be "drained" well before the loop exits. Add `@autoreleasepool {}` around the innermost loop, so that the `stringEquation` strings and `p` predicates be autoreleased frequently:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    stringEquation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.0%@%d.0%@%d.0%@%d.0==24.0"
                     ,[[theNumbers objectAtIndex:a] intValue]
                     ,[someOperators objectAtIndex:v]
                     ,[[theNumbers objectAtIndex:b] intValue]
                     ,[someOperators objectAtIndex:w]
                     ,[[theNumbers objectAtIndex:c] intValue]
                     ,[someOperators objectAtIndex:x]
                     ,[[theNumbers objectAtIndex:d] intValue]];

    p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:stringEquation];

    if ([p evaluateWithObject:nil]) {

        [theMatches addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld,%ld,%ld,%ld,%ld,%ld,%ld",(long)a,(long)b,(long)c,(long)d,(long)v,(long)w,(long)x]];

        fourMatches = fourMatches + 1;

    }
}
```